# What permission do you need to access event0 on Android?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I need to open a certain dev/input/eventx for reading from a JNI lib. What permissions should i request for this, and is it possible to get it without making it a sysem app? Thanks.

Comment: sorry is is not possible

Comment: oh.. sad to hear that. thanks.